# Вывод древовидных комментариев

Tags: laravel

У меня есть таблица и выглядит она так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Название модели `ForumTopic`.

Название таблицы `forum_topics`.

Я вывожу все записи из БД с помощью `foreach`. Есть столбец в базе данных, который хранит `id` комментария, на который я дал ответ. Мне нужно, чтобы выводился ответ к комментарию. А как его вывести - я не знаю.

---

Как получить текст из записи в таблице, зная `id`? Как бы мог я это сделать?

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, отредактировал

Comment: не совсем понял, вы про какой запрос

Comment: Я делаю это так.
 $comments = ForumTopic::all()->where('id_theme', '=', $id);
        return view('forum-detail', [
            'comments' => $comments
        ]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вывода древовидных комментариев перед отправкой во `view` необходимо несколько изменить коллекцию комментариев, например, в контроллере:

```
// Выборка из БД всех комментариев текущей записи с `$id`.
$comments = ForumTopic::where('id_theme', '=', $id)->get();

// Изменяем коллекцию.
$comments->transform(function ($comment) use ($comments) {
  // Добавляем к каждому комментарию дочерние комментарии.
  $comment->children = $comments->where('reply_id', $comment->id);

  return $comment;
});

// Удаляем из коллекции комментарии у которых есть родители.
$comments = $comments->reject(function ($comment) {
  return $comment->reply_id !== null;
});
```

Вывод посредством шаблонизатора *Blade*. Создаются два файла в папке *comments*.

**Файл `area.blade.php`**

```html
<section class="comments">
  <div class="comments__inner">
    <div class="comments__header">
      <h4 class="comments__title">Комментарии</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- Рекурсивное подключение шаблона комментариев. -->
    <ol class="comments__list">
      @each('comments.show', $comments, 'comment')
    </ol>

    <form ...>
      <!-- Тут может быть форма для комментирования. -->
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Файл `show.blade.php`**

```html
<li class="comment">
  <article class="comment__inner">
    <div class="comment__content">{{ $comment->description }}</div>
  </article>

  <!-- Рекурсивное подключение шаблона дочерних комментариев. -->
  <ul class="comments_list__children">
    @each('comments.show', $comment->children, 'comment')
  </ul>
</li>
```

Теперь подключаем шаблон во вьюшке, где необходимо вывести список комментариев:

```
@include('comments.area', ['comments' => $comments])
```

Answer (score 0):

Во время выполнения foreach() внутри сделай проверку, мол если id комментария совпадает с id комментария ответа, то сделать например не просто `<p>Комментарий</p>`, а `<p style="background: yellow;">Комментарий</p>`

Comment: Это не совсем то что нужно. Даже если id совпадет с id ответа, то он будет возвращать только те у которого id == relate_id.

Answer (score 0):

В моделе : 
...    public function answers (){return $this->where('reply_id', $this->id)}

В методе где тянешь  коменти:Comment::where('reply_id',null)->with('answers')->get()
Далее:foreach()...$comment->answers отдаст список всіх ответов