# Laravel вывод комментариев в виде иерархической структуры

Tags: php, laravel

Модель: 
id, model_id, model_type, parent_id, comment, даты.

parent_id - id записи комментария, на который даётся ответ, если это комментарий непосредственно к странице, то parent_id=null.
В шаблоне страницы, где включены комментарии:

```
@include(comments, [$comments])
```

Шаблон комментария с рекурсивным выводом: comments.blade.php

```
@foreach($comment as $coment)
{{$comment}}

@include(comments, [$comments, $comment->replies ])
@endforeach
```

**При этом подходе есть 2 проблемы**:

1. Повторный вывод комментариев в цикле из-за рекурсии, решаю занесением их в массив с последующей проверкой:

   if(!in_array($comment->id, $printed_comments)

Не очень красиво, но пока лучше ничего не придумал, если есть идеи подскажите варианты.

2. Сдвиг комментариев вправо.

Проблема в том, что тут нужно знать состояние предыдущего комментария. А тут вообще идей простой и логичной реализации не могу придумать.
Создавать второй массив, где хранить id и вложенность?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975803/256824

Comment: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset